# Nous vous proposons « de se réunir » ou Nous vous proposons « de nous réunir » ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes-pronominaux

Quelle phrase est correcte :

> Nous vous proposons de **se** réunir.

ou

> Nous vous proposons de **nous** réunir.

Pouvez-vous s'il vous plaît m'énoncer la règle ?

Answer (score 4):

Le pronom personnel « se » s'emploie à la troisième personne du singulier ou du pluriel.

Il est donc incompatible avec « nous vous proposons » qui suivant le sens implique « nous réunir » ou « vous réunir » :

> Nous vous proposons de **nous** réunir. (« Nous » et « vous » **nous** réunissons )
>
> Nous vous proposons de **vous** réunir. (« Vous » **vous** réunissez sans « nous »)

On dira en revanche:

> Nous leur proposons de **se** réunir. (« Ils » **se** réunissent sans « nous » ni « vous »)